# SSL Certificate Expiry: Does the expiry time make any difference at all?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I need to know when an SSL certificate actually expires. Does it just look at the expiry date, or does it also take into account the expiry time?

Let's say a certificate expired on 1/1/2013 at 11am. Does that certificate expire at 11:01am or is it only the following day that the certificate expires? I have been told both are true.

Hope that makes sense! Our suppliers messed up and let our certificate expire, and I'm trying to figure out how much compensation we're owed.

I found this question [Details on exact expiration datetime of an SSL certificate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/339469/details-on-exact-expiration-datetime-of-an-ssl-certificate) but it didn't quite answer what I need (and I didn't like to revive a dead question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have a time as well as a date.  Taking one of my own certificates, obtained with `openssl s_client`, and putting it into `openssl x509 -text -noout`, I find (amongst other things) that:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 513100 (0x7d44c)
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=GeoTrust, Inc., CN=RapidSSL CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 16 06:07:05 2012 GMT
            Not After : Oct 16 09:42:56 2016 GMT
```

As you can see, the certificate is very precise about when it expires.  Yours should be, too.

Comment: Thanks! So am I right in saying that with your example at Oct 16 10:00:00 2016 GMT the browsers would then kick up a fuss saying the certificate is no longer valid? Just wanna be crystal clear!

Comment: That's client-dependent (ie, it's up to the browser), but it's certainly what you'd expect a well-behaved browser to do.  If your suppliers claim certificates expire on a day, they're wrong; they expire on a second, as I've shown.  But if they claim that *some* browsers don't care until the following day, they should be asked which browsers, and for some proof.

Answer (score 3):

The expiration time is down to the second. It really shouldn't matter though since the certificate should be renewed / migrated / etc weeks in advance in any professional organization.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I know. I even reminded said profesional organisation about it a month ago. They're saying that the expiry time doesn't matter though, and that it is only the following day, that the certificate expires and browsers complain.

Comment: @CYMR0, whether or not browsers complain based on the time may well be browser dependant.